# Add a Video with background CSS property

Tags: css

how do i put this

```
background-position: center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 1000px;
```

as a video property in css?

Answer (score 0):

`video` tag supports `object-fit: cover`, instead of `background-size`. And it's centered by default.

```
.my-video-class{
 object-fit: cover;
 min-height: 1000px;
}
```